# Promises - I get the same result after $q.all

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, promise, angular-promise

I have this code:

```
return WordPress.getAllCategories()
  .then(function (cats) {
  var category = {};
  $q.all(cats.data.map(function (cat) {
    return WordPress.getLatestPostOfCategory(cat.id)
      .then(function (post) {
        return WordPress.getMediaById(post.data.featured_media)
          .then(function (media) {

            console.log('post id: ' + post.data.id);

            console.log('Post title: ' + post.data.title.rendered);

            category.post = {};
            category.post.id = post.data.id;
            category.post.title = post.data.title.rendered;
            category.post.content = post.data.content.rendered;

            var splitted = category.post.content.split('<p><!--more--></p>');
            category.post.introAsHtml = splitted[0];
            category.post.contentAsHtml = splitted[1];

            category.post.thumbnail = media.data.source_url;

            return category;
          });
      });
  })).then(function (res) {
    console.log(res);
  });
});
```

To load latest articles from each category for a magazine main page (using WordPress REST api with $http requests). The process is as follow:
1. Load all categories.
2. Get latest post from each category.
3. Get the media of the latest post.
4. Build the `category.post` object based on the post data and add the thumbnail from the media received (post-specific).
5. After all promises are resolved, `$scope.categories = categories` to apply for view.

**The problem:**

With the code above, I can see the console logs search for different posts and medias properly, but at the end I get an array containing the categories, all posts are the same. Same title, content, thumbnail image and everything.

What am I doing wrong with the promises here?

P.S. All `WordPresss` service functions work properly. They return a resolved promise after receiving the necessary data via $http requests from the WordPress blog.

Regards.

Comment: You forgot to `return` the `$q.all(…)` from the `then` callback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way:

```
return WordPress.getAllCategories()
  .then(function (cats) {
  $q.all(cats.data.map(function (cat) {
    return WordPress.getLatestPostOfCategory(cat.id)
      .then(function (post) {
        return WordPress.getMediaById(post.data.featured_media)
          .then(function (media) {

            console.log('post id: ' + post.data.id);

            console.log('Post title: ' + post.data.title.rendered);

            var category = {}; // moved declaration here to return new instance each time
            category.post = {};
            category.post.id = post.data.id;
            category.post.title = post.data.title.rendered;
            category.post.content = post.data.content.rendered;

            var splitted = category.post.content.split('<p><!--more--></p>');
            category.post.introAsHtml = splitted[0];
            category.post.contentAsHtml = splitted[1];

            category.post.thumbnail = media.data.source_url;

            return category;
          });
      });
  })).then(function (res) {
    console.log(res);
  });
});
```

You were returning same category object instance, I just create new instance every time inside `getMediaById` callback

Comment: I will. Can you please explain what you did here?

Comment: it works. Can you please edit and explain what you did there? I will also set this as answer. Thanks a lot man!

Comment: You were returning same category object instance every time, I just declare it every time inside `getMediaById` callback

Comment: Basically just set the new category inside at the end block?

Comment: Thanks a lot @karaxuna!

Comment: @karaxuna - A really good answer has an explanation in plain text, not in the code, about what you changed and why.  That makes your answer more valuable for other people who are reading the question and wondering what the solution was without having to understand and follow every line of code.  Please add such an explanation to your answer.